# Access win10 host desktop from linux guest vm?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, emulation

I have the specific use case, that I want to run stuff mainly from inside the guest VM (pop os 22.04 currently, but I'm open to switching distro if the use case is easier elsewhere), without tabbing out of the fullscreen view to access the Win10 host machine. Basically have my windows host machine desktop open just in an extra tab for GPU intensive tasks or win only software.
(I have to do it that way, since work policy restricts me from deinstalling windows from the host machine).

Currently, I'm just using standard Hyper-V from windows as my hypervisor, where I connect to pop os with xrdp, which is called "enhanced user session" or something like that in Hyper-V. Again, I'm open to switch to VirtualBox or something if that works better for me.

I tried with moonlight / sunshine, and it worked in setting up the connection, but in the end was not sufficient, because when streaming the desktop, it would of course also capture the VM that was open. Also, as I do not plan on passing through the GPU to the linux guest (without hacks I dont want to do on a work machine only available on win server versions), so I'm not sure if the software encoding will be eye cancer. But if I could for example just exclude the VM window from being captured by sunshine desktop streaming, that would hit my use case.

I also thought about using lookingglass somehow (as it is usually intended for running on a windows guest machine, which theoretically would still work if windows is the host), but I didn't find a possibility to create a shared memory on baremetal windows to pass to the linux guest machine.

What I didnt try: I thought about using steamlink for that, as it is also possible to stream the desktop with it, but I was reluctant as I would use it in a commercial setting, where I'm not sure I'm allowed to do that.

Thx for any help, it is really appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, friend, SW recommendations are [off topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in SU, so this may well get closed. They're on topic in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't really understand. I do have Hyper-V running here. Move your mouse over to the Windows machine.  Run the equivalent of RDP in the Linux System to access Windows.  Best to have an external network switch for the Linux guest.

Comment: I can't just rdp into windows, because it allows only one user being logged in at the same time, which is of course the case when there is a host running the VM in the background. Just moving the mouse over, I find that too annyoing, I'd very much prefer to have it an extra window inside the linux vm.

Comment: The guest stays running when windows logs off or shuts down, but yes, I did forget that if you sign out of Windows that the guest is not accessible. Moving the mouse is not much of a handicap. If you can get Radmin Server installed on the Windows desktop, you can access a working session with Radmin Viewer.  I do this

Comment: NoMachine doesn't log your desktop user out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use instead of RDP a
[VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)
product that uses the current host login, so there would be no conflicts.

You could use the free and open-source
[UltraVNC](https://uvnc.com/)
or any of its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/ultra-vnc/)
that are free to use in your environment.

You may need to install the VNC product on the host
as a service that will start with the computer.
If you don't want to need to confirm the connection
inside the host session, you may create a permanent password
(depending on the capabilities of the product you choose).